# how do I break into columns as the screen gets smaller

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap on my site and I have a couple of div like below

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
           <div id="item1" class="col-sm-6">
              some content
           </div>
           <div id="item2" class="col-sm-6">
              some content
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
           <div id="item3" class="col-sm-6">
              some content
           </div>
           <div id="item4" class="col-sm-6">
              some content
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

My code example is wrong above or I wouldn't need to ask questions here. When the screen is md or larger I would like the content of the items to display like below

```
item1 item2 item3 item4
```

the items just go across the screen in one row, this is easy to do. Now when I want it to do the following when the screen size is sm or xs

```
item1 item2
item3 item4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired classes, divide 12 by the number of columns you want to get:

For 4 columns, 12 / 4 = 3 -> for example `col-md-3 col-lg-3`

For 2 columns, 12 / 2 = 6 -> for example `col-xs-6 col-sm-6`

Note: This applies to rows that go across the full page, not to elements nested inside other columns. In the code below I have removed the elements in-between the outer row and your "Item" containers.

```
<div class="row">
       <div id="item1" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          some content
       </div>
       <div id="item2" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          some content
       </div>
       <div id="item3" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          some content
       </div>
       <div id="item4" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          some content
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just:

```
<div class="row">
       <div id="item1" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          some content 1
       </div>
       <div id="item2" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          some content 2
       </div>
       <div id="item3" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          some content 3
       </div>
       <div id="item4" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          some content 4
       </div>
</div>
```